# Infinite loop of 'Stay on page?' popups while typing a Stack Overflow question

Tags: support, bug, firefox, mac

In Firefox on Mac OS, the 2-finger-swipe gesture is a shortcut for `forward` and `back`. This is often handy, but sometimes I use the gesture by accident.

When I accidentally do a "go back" swipe while writing a Stack Overflow question, I get the popup shown below. No big deal, I just click "stay on page" an go on my merry way, right? Not so fast. Regardless of whether I click `Stay on Page` or `Leave Page`, **the popup comes back over and over**. Presumably, the popup would reappear an infinite number of times, but I usually do `killall firefox` to just close Firefox and start over.
**Is this a common problem? If so, what can we do about it?**

[image]